# Android Integer to String time format

Tags: android, time, format

I have integers that I pull from resources.  They are times but since I have to store them as an integer in the resource file I store 9 minutes and 8 seconds as 0908.  I want to display this as 09:08 on the screen but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I'm sure there is an easy way but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Why don't you store the date as a Unix timestamp (long) in the resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
String result = String.format("%02d:%02d", intTime / 100, intTime % 100);
```

Comment: Nice and simple, thanks.  I do have one question though, what is intTime % 100?

Comment: This is modulo operation: 1234 % 100 -> 34. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", intTime / 100, intTime % 100);

Answer (score 0):

You could either split it using some math ( divide by 100 for minutes and modulo 100 for seconds)

or you could use SimpleDateFormat to parse and/or display. http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html